# POSTGRES 9.6: How do I make a disaggregation in percentages of each column of a table on a single query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, jsonb, postgresql-9.6

I have a table that store information on user clicks, like "so","browser","timezone". I need to make a dissaggregation of each column to build a pie chart of each one. I would need a json result like:

```
{"results": {
              "browser":[{"name":"Chrome","qty":50,"percentage:"50"},
                         {"name":"Firefox","qty":50,"percentage:"50"}], "SO":[{"name":"Linux","qty":50,"percentage:"50"},{"name":"WIndows","qty":50,"percentage:"50"}]} }
```

The table definition is:

```
=================================
TABLE DEFINITION
=================================

Column  Type    Comment
sponsor_ad_click_id integer Auto Increment [nextval('ad_clicks_ad_click_id_seq')]    
sponsor_ad_id   integer  
clicked_date    timestamptz  
browser text NULL    
os  text NULL    
device  text NULL    
continent_code  text NULL    
continent_name  text NULL    
country_code    text NULL    
country_name    text NULL    
timezone    text NULL    
ip  text NULL    
social_network_id   smallint NULL [1]    
sponsor_id  integer
```

I've tried subqueries but I can only return one value from each one,

```
  SELECT (select count(spac2.browser) FROM sponsor_ad_clicks spac2 where spac2.sponsor_ad_id = spac.sponsor_ad_id),
                     (select count(spac2.os) FROM sponsor_ad_clicks spac2 wheer spac2.sponsor_ad_id = spac.sponsor_ad_id),
                     (select count(spac2.device) FROM sponsor_ad_clicks spac2 where spac2.sponsor_ad_id = spac.sponsor_ad_id),
                     (select count(spac2.continent_name) FROM sponsor_ad_clicks spac2 where spac2.sponsor_ad_id = spac.sponsor_ad_id),
                     (select count(spac2.country_name) FROM sponsor_ad_clicks spac2 where spac2.sponsor_ad_id = spac.sponsor_ad_id),
                     (select count(spac2.timezone) FROM sponsor_ad_clicks spac2 where spac2.sponsor_ad_id = spac.sponsor_ad_id)
              FROM sponsor_ad_clicks spac
              WHERE spac.sponsor_ad_id = 2
```

Which obviously is not correct since it returns only one value per subquery,

I've also tried to build a json array without any luck,any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete solution, but more a hint where to move. I aggregate over a browser column. The late hour and absence of data sample in your question limit me to this. Anyway, to add another metrics, just `partition over column_name` and add it to built json. Also you might want to use `json_build` instead of `concat` and casts. Again - lack of info in your question...

```
t=# \pset format unaligned
Output format is unaligned.
t=# with j as (
  with agg as (
    select distinct
      count(1) over (partition by browser) qty
    , browser
    , count(1) over (partition by true) total
    from sponsor_ad_clicks
  )
  select
    browser as "name"
  , qty
  , qty*100/total percentage
  from agg
)
select
  jsonb_pretty(concat('{"result":{"browser":',array_to_json(array_agg(to_json(j))),'}}')::jsonb) r
from j
;
r
{
    "result": {
        "browser": [
            {
                "qty": 2,
                "name": "chrome",
                "percentage": 40
            },
            {
                "qty": 3,
                "name": "ie",
                "percentage": 60
            }
        ]
    }
}
(1 row)
```